# How to retrieve Stored Procedure schema using Linq to SQL?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, linq, linq-to-sql

Basically I am trying to retrieve a list of stored procedure parameters using Linq to SQL?  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At design time?  Just drag the stored procedure on to the LINQ designer surface.

---

At runtime?

You need sql like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM syscolumns
WHERE id =
(
  SELECT id
  FROM sysobjects
  WHERE Name = @ProcName
)
```

Which might be generated by LinqToSql like this:

```
var params = 
  db.sysobjects
  .Where(o => o.Name == ProcName)
  .SelectMany(o =>
    db.syscolumns
    .Where(c => c.id == o.id)
  )
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommandbuilder.deriveparameters.aspx) will help.